# C# - EF4 - Get the server's DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a fat-client application which uses EF4 to MSSQL in the data layer. Before using EF4 (in plain ADO.Net) I used to have a wrapper function which gets the SQL server's DateTime.Now (a simple `SELECT GETDATE()` wrapped in a C# client call).

Now I find that using SQL funcs and SPs which return simple value types is not-so-simple in EF4. What's the simplest&most efficent way to get the server's datetime-now in this scenario?

I'd like to avoid creating a wrapper entity for this, if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DateTime ServerDate = Entities.CreateQuery<DateTime>("CurrentDateTime()").AsEnumerable().First();
```

Comment: Excellent. I assume CurrentDateTime() is some kind of an EF function, and it works for other providers besides MSSQL?

Comment: converts to `SELECT SysDateTime();`